# python - Вызов функции через кортеж

Tags: python, функции

Есть функция `def f(x,y,z=False):...`.
Есть атрибут класса j, который кортеж и содержит в себе несколько элементов, один внутри вложенный. Например, `j = ((f, (x,y)), (fb, (x,y)))`. 
При вызове функции в коде следующим образом

```
for elem in myclass.j:
    elem[0](elem[1])
```

выдаёт ошибку TypeError: f() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'.
По сути я вызвал f((x,y)). Не понимаю как сделать, чтобы заработало.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка сообщает, что вы передали недостаточно аргументов в функцию, делайте итерацию по двум элементам и точно укажите индексы для всех аргументов:

```
def f(x, y): return x+y
for f, args in ((f, (1, 2)), (f, (3, 5))):
    print(f(args[0], args[1]))

# 3
# 8
```

Также можете использовать распаковку - в python `*`. Ключевое преимущество, которое даёт `*` - это возможность распаковки последовательностей неизвестной длины. Допустим в вашей задачи функции принимают разные наборы аргументов:

```
def f(x, y): return x + y
def fb(x, y, z): return x + y + z
def fbt(a, b, c, x, y, z): return a + b + c + x + y + z
j = ((f, (1, 2)), (fb, (1, 2, 3)), (fbt, (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)))
for func, args in j:
    print(func, args)
    print(func(*args))
# <function f at 0x7fef6fe41bf8> 1 2
# 3
# <function fb at 0x7fef6fe41c80> 1 2 3
# 6
# <function fbt at 0x7fef6fe41d08> 1 2 3 4 5 6
# 21
```

Если аргументы не сформированы в кортеж, то можно использовать следующий синтаксис:

```
k = ((f, 1, 2), (fb, 1, 2, 3), (fbt, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))
for func, *args in k:
    print(func, *args)
    print(func(*args))
```

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так:

```
$ python
Python 3.7.0 (default, Jul 15 2018, 10:44:58) 
[GCC 8.1.1 20180531] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def f(x, y):
...    print(x + y)
... 
>>> args = 40, 2
>>> f(*args)
42
>>> j = ((f, (1, 2)), (f, (7, 7)))
>>> for i in j:
...    i[0](*i[1])
... 
3
14
```

И еще есть такой синтаксис:

```
>>> def g(**kwargs):
...    for key in kwargs:
...        print(key, "->", kwargs[key])
... 
>>> args = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> g(**args)
a -> 1
b -> 2
```

Comment: Базовое описание — это, собственно, https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls — а вообще, разные туториалы можно искать по словам pythong asterisk argument, и т.п. Как по-русски, не знаю. >_>